# Linux networking essentials

Tags: linux, linux-networking

Can someone suggest a book which contains all the essentials required for linux networking. I need something that common to all linux distributions rather than specific distribution.

Thank you
Bala

Answer (score 3):

O'Reilly books are where it's at for Open Source.  Here's a few that should get you started..

- [Linux in a Nutshell](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596154486/)
- [Linux Networking Cookbook](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596102487/)
- [Understanding Linux Network Internals](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596002558/)

Comment: Most of the networking stuff is the same across distributions, at least to a large extent. It would probably also be useful to get a few general books on networking. Once you understand NAT, BGP, RIP, subnetting, etc. it's just a matter of command/config file syntax, whether you're on Linux, Windows or Cisco.

Comment: Totally with Kyle and Jason on their points.

Answer (score 2):

If none of the books appeal to you (Warner's recommendations look good), the following homework assignments might get you up to speed:

Set up a Linux box as a router by having it route between different networks, then on this box, do the following:

- Set up a firewall between the networks with basic accept and deny rules.  For extra credit, find some modules that will filter out certain qualities within packets, not just ports.
- Set up NAT from one network to the other, designate one as the 'internal' network
- In the internal network, setup some sort of service like apache, and then set up port fowarding while NAT is still on so it can be reached from the 'external' network.
- Set up another Linux box as a router, and have these to communicate using a routing protocol such as EGP, RIP, OSPF, or BGP.
- When doing any of the above, capture some packets with tcpdump from the commandline, then view the packet dump in wireshark to aid in trouble shooting.

Do the above by googling for tutorials, reading manuals, and asking questions on here or IRC when you get stuck.  If you accomplish all of the above, I would say you are quite accomplished in Linux networking.

Comment: Good suggestions. Where can I find tutorials to complete the homework above?

Answer (score 2):

It isn't a book, but the [Linux Advanced Routing & Traffic Control HOWTO](http://lartc.org/howto/) has a lot of detail that cover some of the advanced usages and configurations.